# How To Convert To String Search In SPARQL

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I want to use a string instead of the Wikidata ID#.

The code below works perfectly using wd:Q2263 (Tom Hanks) to show what films (Q11424) he was cast (P161) in.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription
WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q11424; wdt:P161 wd:Q2263.
  ?article schema:about ?item;
    schema:name ?title;
    schema:inLanguage "en";
    schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
LIMIT 10
```

The problem is that I want to change wd:Q2263 (Tom Hanks) to be a string like: item ?label "Tom Hanks"@en. 
On my website, I am using a search box, so in the code I need the name of the person to be a string. I don't want to have to look it up in Wikipedia to get the Wikidata ID.

Comment: and why don't you use the label then instead of the URI?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription
WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q11424; wdt:P161/rdfs:label "Tom Hanks"@en.
  ?article schema:about ?item;
    schema:name ?title;
    schema:inLanguage "en";
    schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
LIMIT 10`

Comment: Note, multiple entities with the same label are possible, a label is **not** unique compared to a Wikidata  URI.

Comment: @AKSW Yes, I tried your code and that is exactly what I needed, thanks!